# Adobe AIR NativeProcess not sending input

Tags: c#, .net, actionscript-3, flash, air

There's the problem: I am trying to get a Adobe AS3 app made in Flash Builder communicate with the console. My console application uses .NET 4.5.2, but it does not seem to be reading the input. It works with a .NET 3.5 console app, but for me it is essential for it to work with .NET 4.5.2.

[This person has a similar problem but was not able to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532442/air-nativeprocess-standardinput-not-connecting-to-app/14551282#14551282)

Let me know if anyone knows a way around this.

Comment: I added the `.net` tag. If the AIR app works with .NET 3.5 then the issue would likely be with .NET 4.5.2 – so your title is perhaps not accurate: AIR is sending the data but the console app isn't reading it.

Comment: I fixed this by making another console app that runs on .NET 3.5, which opens the 4.5.2 console app and passes input to it